# Assigned attribute is None in a Process

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Consider the following peice of code.

```
from multiprocessing import Process


class A(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        super(A, self).__init__()

    def run(self) -> None:
        self.a = 4

    def print_a(self):
        print(self.a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = A()
    b.start()
    b.print_a()
```

I want output to be :-

4

But after running the code, the output is :-

None

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

---

My final Remarks :-

I am a noob in Python. I used to use Thread in java, and we never had such issue there. Initially, i didn't knew there is a godly class like threading in python too.

Simply put, what i wanted to do, is just the thing for which we use threading's Thread class. After using that, all my issues are fixed. The code I provided above is just a simple enact of the actual code where the shared variable is a non-Picklable class Web3 and it was giving me tons of problems with multiprocessing. It's just that my understanding and knowledge of python was shallow. I didn't realise that having a seperate memory for variables is what Process is for...

Comment: ``multiprocessing`` does not share memory by default – the ``self.a`` slot in the subprocess is not the same as the ``self.a`` in the main process.

Comment: Is there a way to have shared attributes ?